# How to show 1-5 of X Total Results

Tags: categories, pagination

I know I'm doing something that's been done 1000's of times before in WordPress, but struggling to get the terms to find it on the Interwebs.

I've got a custom category template page and have a while loop that shows the first 5 results (of which there are more than 5).

How do I output something within my while that shows the relative position in the results and the total number:

I know how to get the post count:

```
<?php
   $catcount = new WP_Query( 'cat=4&posts_per_page=-1' );
?>
```

But not sure how to setup the pagination and the relative results, meaning

Results 1-10 of `<?php echo $total->found_posts; ?>`

How do I get the results values 1 of 2 and then create pagination for subsequent pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's been a long time, I had exact the same task and here is the solution

```
$from = ($query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] * $paged) - ($query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] - 1);
if(($query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] * $paged) <= ($query->found_posts)){
  $to = ($query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] * $paged);
}else{
  $to = $query->found_posts;
}
if($from == $to){
  $from_to = $from;
}else{
  $from_to = $from.' - '.$to;
}
```

It's not the perfect code, but it works in most of situation.
Have a nice day!)

Comment: Is this some code from inside a callback hooked to some action or filter?

Comment: no, it's code for custom query

Comment: Yes, but it has to run _somewhere_.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with the default WP_Query you can do something like in your loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $paged = !empty($wp_query->query_vars['paged']) ? $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : 1;
    $prev_posts = ( $paged - 1 ) * $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'];
    $from = 1 + $prev_posts;
    $to = count( $wp_query->posts ) + $prev_posts;
    $of = $wp_query->found_posts;

    // ... Display the information, for example
    printf( '%s to %s of %s', $from, $to, $of );

    // Then your normal loop
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

If you are working with a custom query you could do it like this:

```
$myquery = new WP_Query($yourqueryargs);
if ( $myquery->have_posts() ) {
    $paged = !empty($myquery->query_vars['paged']) ? $myquery->query_vars['paged'] : 1;
    $prev_posts = ( $paged - 1 ) * $myquery->query_vars['posts_per_page'];
    $from = 1 + $prev_posts;
    $to = count( $myquery->posts ) + $prev_posts;
    $of = $myquery->found_posts;

    // ... Display the information, for example
    printf( '%s to %s of %s', $from, $to, $of );

    // Then your normal loop
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Even better** - Create a function that you can use either with the global $wp_query or with any custom query.

```
function myThemePostsNow ( $query = null ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( isset($query) && !($query instanceof WP_Query) ) {
        return; // Cancel if a query has been set and is not a WP_Query instance
    }
    elseif ( !isset($query) ) {
        $query = $wp_query; // If $query is not set, use global $wp_query data
    }

    if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
        return; // Cancel if $query don't have posts
    }

    // If we made it here it means we have a WP_Query with posts

    $paged = !empty($query->query_vars['paged']) ? $query->query_vars['paged'] : 1;
    $prev_posts = ( $paged - 1 ) * $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'];
    $from = 1 + $prev_posts;
    $to = count( $query->posts ) + $prev_posts;
    $of = $query->found_posts;

    // Return the information
    return sprintf( '%s to %s of %s', $from, $to, $of );
}
```

Then just call your function

```
if ( have_posts() ) {

    echo myThemePostsNow();

    while ( have_posts() ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

or in a custom query like:

```
if ( $myquery->have_posts() ) {

    echo myThemePostsNow();

    // Then your normal loop
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok so, This following is how you can have custom wp query with pagination, I also suggest you install this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/
This makes life easier :) Once you install this plugin, you can add this code to a custom page template, archive pages, category page in your theme.

```
        <?php
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post', //custom post type as well
            'posts_per_page' => 5, //number of posts per page
            'paged' => $paged,
            'cat' => $catID, //category ID
        );
        $magic_all_posts_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
        ?>     
        <?php
        if ( $cn_all_posts_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $magic_all_posts_query->have_posts() ) : $cn_all_posts_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="entry-single <?php echo $class ?>">
             <h1 class="entry-title">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                       <?php the_title(); ?>
                  </a>
             </h1>
             <div class="entry-content">
                  <?php
                       $content = get_the_content();
                  ?>
             </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;
            wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $cn_all_posts_query ) );
        ?>
```

Do let us know if you run into any roadblocks with this.

Comment: Sorry.. new to this, can you give more info?